# Diffrence between running once and infinite

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming

```
const int ledPin = 12;

void setup(){
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    if (Serial.available()) {
        light(Serial.read() – '0');
    }
    delay(500);
}

void light(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        delay(100);
    }
}
```

by [Oscar Liang](https://oscarliang.com/connect-raspberry-pi-and-arduino-usb-cable/)

awesome little piece of code which taught me how to setup connection by serial. yet one part I don't understand fully. Why does this line:

> light(Serial.read() – '0');

make the code run once,
and this line an infinite times.

> light(Serial.read());

has this something to do with binary? I don't get why subtracting the string 0 would run the code once.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serial.read() -'0'

Such code is often used to convert a character to a digit (e.g. int).

Like if the character is '2', than '2' - '0' = ascii 50 - ascii 48 = 2

However, if you use

```
Serial.read()
```

the value will be 50 instead of 2.... maybe looping 50 times (or 48 to 58, for values 0 to 9) will give you the impression it runs infinite?

Comment: oh wow Thank you, so that is just a way to convert to a int. Never knew that!

Comment: Yes, it is a way to convert one digit (so a character from '0' to '9') to an integer. Nb if this answer is good, consider upvoting and accepting it as your answer.

Comment: cant upvote yet. I don't have enough rep, but you will get it in the end :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting. No problem (geen probleem). Enjoy programming!